# Not able to serialize List<Object> to json using resteasy jackson provider and jaxb annotations

Tags: resteasy

I have added `resteasy-jackson` provider jar in my `pom.xml`
I have one pojo class annotated with jaxb annotations :

**Request.java**

```
@XmlElement
public List<Object> getListSO() {
    return listSO;
}
```

I have written an resteasy client to access a rest webservice.  I am passing this request object as a parameter to webservice.

**Rest Webservice**

```
@POST
@Path("/authorizefields")
@Produces("application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1")
@Consumes("application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1")
public Reply getFields(Request request) {
}
```

Now from rest client if i add some object to list say

```
listSO.add(new Sample());
request.setListSO(listSO);
```

and pass it to the rest webservice I am not able to get sample object in ws.
Is there any jaxb or jackson annotation needed to put on list of object to support polymorphism?